# Return a shared value from multiple rows by filtering on multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server table with columnar data in it. Each row has a `CardID`, `IndexType`, and a `StringVal`. I need to return the distinct `CardID` based on `IndexType` and `StringVal` that may be in multiple rows.

Here is some example data:

```
declare @cardindexes table ([ID] int, [CardID] int,
                            [IndexType] int, [StringVal] nvarchar(255))

INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'Bunnies')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'playing')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (3, 1, 3, 'yahtzee')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (5, 2, 1, 'Puppies')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (6, 2, 1, 'Dogs')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (7, 2, 2, 'playing')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (8, 2, 3, 'poker')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (10, 3, 1, 'Dogs')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (11, 3, 2, 'playing')
INSERT INTO @cardindexes VALUES (12, 3, 3, 'fetch')
```

This query returns as I would expect-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CardID 
FROM @cardindexes 
WHERE (IndexType = 2 AND StringVal = 'playing');
```

Returns:

```
CardID
1
2
3
```

But when I try to narrow it down further, I can't get any results-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CardID 
FROM @cardindexes 
WHERE (IndexType = 1 AND StringVal = 'Dogs') 
  AND (IndexType = 2 AND StringVal = 'playing');
```

Returns no results, but I would want

```
CardID
2
3
```

To take it even further-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CardID 
FROM @cardindexes 
WHERE (IndexType = 1 AND StringVal = 'Dogs')
  AND (IndexType = 2 AND StringVal = 'playing')
  AND (IndexType = 3 AND StringVal = 'poker');
```

Returns no results, but I would want

```
CardID
2
```

I know that the above queries will not work because I am looking at different rows and trying to use `AND`, but `OR` is not an option either as it returns CardIDs that do not match ALL of the criteria. I'm not sure which direction to go to get the result I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CardID 
FROM @cardindexes 
WHERE CardID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT CardID FROM @cardindexes WHERE (IndexType = 1 AND StringVal = 'Dogs'))
AND CardID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT CardID FROM @cardindexes WHERE (IndexType = 2 AND StringVal = 'playing'))
AND CardID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CardID FROM @cardindexes WHERE (IndexType = 3 AND StringVal = 'poker'));
```

Comment: This won't do it. He does want to meet _all_ of the conditions... just for different rows.

Comment: got it. made a change

Comment: @ElenaDBA This appears to work for me in that it returns the right result. Is there a performance hit by adding the additional AND/SELECT DISTINCT? I ask as this was a simple example with 3 columns, but it could in fact be 5-10 or more?

Comment: you could try removing distinct from the subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Each set of conditions is looking at different row. To evaluate these different rows at the same time, you have to JOIN the table with itself for each set of conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.CardID 
FROM @cardindexes c1
INNER JOIN @cardindexes c2 ON c2.CardID = c1.CardID 
    AND c2.IndexType = 2 AND c2.StringVal = 'playing'
INNER JOIN @cardindexes c3 ON c2.CardID = c2.CardID 
    AND c3.IndexType = 3 AND c3.StringVal = 'poker'
WHERE c1.IndexType = 1 AND c1.StringVal = 'Dogs'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this query returns 2 & 3, when it should only return 2.